# How to detect mouse moving while left button down

Tags: asp.net, javascript, stylesheet

I want to use javascript to detect the mouse position once the mousedown event has fired.  It appears I am not getting an onmousemove event when the left button is held down.  The cursor is changing to some circle with a cross through it.

My whole goal is to detect the start position of the cursor on mousedown and change the top left style of a image in a div with overflow set (kind of fake pan effect).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set up an [ondragstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536928(VS.85).aspx) handler:

```
function dragstart(ev)
{
    if (!ev) ev = window.event;
    ev.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}

image.ondragstart = dragstart;
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be an attribute for an html img or an asp img object tag

i am trying to do it for an asp page, if that matters.

Comment: Oh, that's Javascript code. I'm not sure what you might need to do to have the same effect in ASP.